# Change Icon on Task Bar for VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a program in vb.net which is ready to be published.

Its a small detail, but I'd like to change the icon on both the published app shortcut on my desktop, but more importantly on my taskbar (like where the chrome circle shows up).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the main icon for your application, go to the "Application" tab under the project property page, and change the "Icon:" combo box.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks so much. My only question is... is there a way to make any picture I have into the .ico file that is required? I tried going in paint and simply saving it as .ico. It showed up in the browser to select, but it said it was an invalid icon file. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Microangelo is a good tool for converting images to icons and icon libraries.  http://www.microangelo.us/icon-editor.asp

Comment: ICO files are a special icon file format which actually store multiple bitmap images in a single file.  To make an icon look nice in all situations, you'll want to make sure it includes a 16x16 image for small icon lists, a 32x32 image for normal large icon lists, a 48x48 image for Vista and later really-large icon lists, etc.  Also, it's good to include different color depth images at each size too (256 color, 16 bit, etc).  So there is no simple way to properly create an ICO file by simply saving a single image as an ICO file type.

Comment: There are many free icon editors out there.  As @RobertBeaubien suggested, I also use MicroAngelo, but there are other good ones out there.  A quick google search for "free icon editor" came up with this page, for instance: http://speckyboy.com/2008/05/03/top-5-free-icon-editors-for-the-pro-designer/

Comment: @steveDog That actually didn't end up working. I made the icon using one of the editors listed on the page you linked to, and then changed the icon using your instructions. I launched my app in vb and it did not change anything. I then tried publishing and seeing if that worked and it did not either. Ideas?

Comment: That should change the icon of the EXE file itself when you view it in the explorer.  Did it do that?  If that's not enough, you may need to change the icon on your forms as well.