# How to change a program Icon in taskbar (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, icons

Would like to ask how can i set my own icon instead of default icon displayed by vb.net? Thanks in advance. It seems hard to find a solution in Google as i don't know what keyword should i search because all the result show me changing the .exe icon.

[image]

[image]

Had tried to change the icon in project properties but it's not working..

Comment: well, there is option to change it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11581373/324900

Comment: had tried but it's not working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change icon form from properties form like this picture.

[image: chang icon form taskbar]

Answer (score 4):

The Icon you set on the above window is the default program icon. to change the taskbar icon you need to set the currently showing form's icon.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Form Icon Change]

Change your Form's icon prom the property tab of the form of your application.
If there is a single form, you only need to change it, but if there's multiple, you need to change all of them individually.

Hope it helps! :)